# Javascript validate CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I know about this subject is repeated but I don't know what I'm doing wrong... See my code:

```
alert(CKEDITOR.instances.MyToolbar.getData()); // i see this alert...
if (CKEDITOR.instances.MyToolbar.getData() == 0) {
    document.getElementById('wystaw_s3').classList.add("red");
    document.getElementById('MyToolbar').classList.add("redborder");
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('wystaw_s3').classList.remove("red");
    document.getElementById('MyToolbar').classList.remove("redborder");
}
```

Any clue? THX!

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense at all:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.MyToolbar.getData() == 0
```

I guess you wanted to do:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.MyToolbar.getData().length == 0
```